# How to dual boot Ubuntu and Mint

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I have Ubuntu 16.10 installed and bootable on one hard drive, and Mint installed on another drive. Grub sees both OSes but when I try to boot Mint it tells me...

> error: no such device: 50863d03-7bf3-411e-b6208964bfbbc470
>   error: no such partition
>   error: you need to load kernel first...

Any help will be thoroughly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is that the exact wording of the error message you see?

Comment: Yes. When i select Linux Mint it loads this exact wordage:

Comment: Error no such device: (long code)

Comment: error no such partition

Comment: need to load kernel first...

Comment: I don't know the answer myself, but I'll try to help you get answers by offering suggestions on how to improve this question. First, [edit] clarifications intp the question itself, where they're more visible. Second, try to quote exact words, including the "long code" you mention. There's probably useful information in there.

Comment: Long code is probably just UUID.  May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: When selecting Mint to boot I get this: error: no such device: 50863d03-7bf3-etc....  I ran boot-repair but it didn't solve the issue. I suspect it's not finding something in Mint.